# Como aplicar un filtro a un spreadsheet desde script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, hide

Saludos estoy tratando de generar una vista filtrada segun el usuario que accede a mi spreadsheet, hasta ahora solo he logrado que funcione esto:

```
function onOpen(){
 var currentUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Bienvenido "+ currentUser);
 var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheets = spreadSheet.getSheets();
  if (currentUser == "briggittelew@gmail.com"){
   sheets[1].hideSheet();
   var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Trabajos");
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   var range = sheet.getRange("C2:C"+lastRow);
    //var filterRange = {};
    for (i=1; i<lastRow; i++){
     var filterQuestion = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      if (filterQuestion == "Proyecto"){
        sheet.hideRows(i);
      }
     }    
  }
}
```

Pero las filas se pueden mostrar manualmente, estoy intentando este otro código pero no me funciona para nada...

```
function onOpen(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var filterSettings = {};

  // The range of data on which you want to apply the filter.
  // optional arguments: startRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endRowIndex, endColumnIndex
  filterSettings.range = {
    sheetId: ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
  };

  // Criteria for showing/hiding rows in a filter
  // https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria
  filterSettings.criteria = {};
  var columnIndex = 2;
  filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
    'hiddenValues': ["Proyecto"]
  };

  var request = {
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filterSettings
    }
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());

}
```

y me presenta este error:
Ejecución fallida: ReferenceError: "Sheets" no está definido. (línea 25, archivo "Código") [0,003 segundos de tiempo de ejecución total]

Que me estoy saltando? Existe alguna otra solucion???

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, sobre todo esto que dices: *Pero las filas se pueden mostrar manualmente* ... No sé qué quieres decir con eso. No se entiende qué es lo que quieres filtrar en sí.

Comment: Estoy filtrando los valores de una tabla, la idea es que los datos puedan verse o no dependiendo del usuario  (para que pueda editarlos de ser necesario), con el método hide, la fila se oculta pero el usuario puede desplegarla nuevamente, con el método filter no.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más probable es que el error se deba a que aún no has activado el servicio avanzado de las hojas de cálculo de Google.

La forma de habilitarlo se explica en inglés en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services

Donde dice (traducción mía, texto original más abajo):

**Habilitar servicios avanzados**

Para usar un servicio avanzado de Google, sigue estas instrucciones:

1. En el editor de scripts, selecciona Recursos > Servicios avanzados de Google...
2. En el diálogo que se muestra, haz clic en el botón de encendido/apagado a un lado del servicio que quieres usar.
3. En la parte inferior del diálogo, haz clic en el enlace a la Consola de APIs de Google.
4. En la consola, haz clic en la caja de filtro y teclea parte del nombre de la API (por ejemplo, "Calendar"), luego haz clic en el nombre que veas. En la siguiente pantalla, haz clic en Habilitar API.
5. Cierra la Consola de API y regresa al editor de scripts. Haz clic en el diálogo. El servicio avanzado que habilitaste ahora está disoponible en el autocompletado.

> **Enabling advanced services**
>
> To use an advanced Google service, follow these instructions:
>
> 1. In the script editor, select Resources > Advanced Google services....
> 2. In the dialog that appears, click the on/off switch next to the service you want to use.
> 3. At the bottom of the dialog, click the link for the Google API Console.
> 4. In the console, click into the filter box and type part of the name of the API (for example, "Calendar"), then click the name once you see
>      it. On the next screen, click Enable API.
> 5. Close the API Console and return to the script editor. Click OK in the dialog. The advanced service you enabled is now available in
>      autocomplete.